# How to add a command printing only the version to my setup.py

Tags: setuptools

I would like to add a command to my setup.py to print the current version to stdout.
Here is a sample of what I tried (in reality the version is not hardcoded, but how I get it is not relevant to the question):

```
from setuptools import Command, setup


def get_version():
    return "5.2.4"


class PrintVersionCommand(Command):
    user_options = []

    def initialize_options(self):
        pass

    def finalize_options(self):
        pass

    def run(self):
        print(get_version())
    
setup(
    cmdclass={
        "print_version": PrintVersionCommand,
    },
    name='MyPackageName',
    version=get_version(),
    url='https://github.com/mypackage.git',
    author='Author Name',
    author_email='author@gmail.com',
    description='Description of my package',
)
```

The problem with this code is that it prints too much:

```
$ python setup.py print_version
running print_version
5.2.4
```

Is there a way tp not print the `running print_version` log to stdout, so I don't have to do extra parsing of the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `PrintVersionCommand`, it's unnecessary. Run

```
python setup.py --version
```